# Extract variables used in a line of java code?

Tags: java, variables, extract

Suppose we have a line of java code like bellow:

```
MyActivity activity = new MyActivity(activityFile.getName());
```

Is there any tool (a jar file or any piece of java code) to extract variables used in that line of code?
In this case, it should return **activity** and **activityFile** as output.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using Eclipse and the JDT, creating a plugin that piggy-backs onto them to do this using the AST...

Comment: like here: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html